# Cite in caption beamer

Tags: beamer, captions, citing

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\title{Beamer o Beamer}
\author{mishr}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

%slide 0
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Item A \cite{author1} %This works
    \item ItemB


\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{fig}
    \caption{Some figure\protect \cite{Author}}%This doesn't work.
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{pres}
\end{frame}
```

%bib file is named pres.bib

I am using the above in Beamer. The citation gives me [?] after multiple runs. Citation in the text works fine. Any ideas why ?

Edit: MWE added.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Does `\protect` needs any package to be included ?

Comment: That's why we need a MWE to understand the context. You can add a dummy bibliography with filecontents package as in this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68828/referencing-book-ieee/68857#68857 .

Comment: No, `\protect` doesn't require any package, and some simple tests I did with your snippet worked as expected, so please add (as requested by percusse) a MWE:

Comment: That's not a mWe. Try to compile it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problems with the following code. I've removed `\protect`. MikTeX 2.9 and `beamer` 3.20A. I've put the command `\listfiles` in the file so that the version info of the packages printed in the log file.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\listfiles
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} % Irrelevant for the problem but suppresses warnings
\usepackage{mwe}     % Adds the dummy image used and loads graphicx
%\usepackage{tikz}    % Not needed for the problem
%\usepackage{wasysym} % Same here
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{filecontents} % For a dummy bibfile creation
\begin{filecontents*}{mybibfile.bib}
@ARTICLE{authora,
  author = {A. Aaaaa},
  title = {Some article},
  journal = {Journal of Dummy Article Names},
  year = {2012},
  volume = {99},
  pages = {1-5}
}

@ARTICLE{authorb,
  author = {B. Baaaa},
  title = {Another article},
  journal = {Journal of Dummy Article Names},
  year = {2012},
  volume = {99},
  pages = {6-10}
}

\end{filecontents*}



\title{Beamer o Beamer}
\author{mishr}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Item A \cite{authora} %This works
    \item ItemB
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Some figure from \cite{authorb}}%This doesn't work.
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{mybibfile}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]